# Frame limit on browser websocket

Tags: javascript, sockets, chunking

I'm trying to build my own realtime video application and I'm having trouble sending video frames from the webcam up to the server through a websocket. 
I'm using a standard browser websocket without any external library, following the api [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API):

I capture the webcam canvas every 30ms and write it to my websocket.

```
ws = new WebSocket(url);
....
function update(){ 
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
    var data = canvas.get()[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
    blob = dataURItoBlob(data);
    ws.send(blob)
}
....
setInterval(update, 30)
```

And I get this error:

```
CloseEvent {wasClean: true, code: 1009, reason: "Frame size of 91552 bytes exceeds maximum accepted frame size", type: "close", target: WebSocket…}
```

So I realize I need to start writing in chunks. 
**I'm wondering what is the most versatile workaround to this. How do I choose an optimal chunk size?**

Here's the dataURItoBlob function so you understand what it does

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
```